# Defining Holiday weekend indicator variable in User Define Function

Tags: r, datetime, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create an indicator variable that will take a date field in a dataset and create a holiday variable that assigns a 1 to the actual holiday date and a 1 to the weekend prior to the holiday. I am getting close but I cannot seem to get beyond my novice ways of thinking about this problem.
For full context, I have given the code of the fake dataset and the user define function I am working on. I had an earlier post with this same function, but a completely different problem.
My question: How do I create a indicator variable within a user define function that can read a holiday and the weekend before that holiday and assign a 1 for those days and a 0 for non-holiday/ holiday weekend days?

## create a basic dataset of Response and Adspend by Date

```
library(timeDate)
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)
library(plyr)


# setting up some fake data
set.seed(31)
foo <- function(myHour, myDate){
   rlnorm(1, meanlog=0,sdlog=1)*(myHour) + (150*myDate) 
}
Hour <- 1:24
Day <-1:1080
dates <-seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "day", length.out= 1080)
myData <- expand.grid( Day, Hour)
names(myData) <- c("Date","Hour")

myData$Adspend <- apply(myData, 1, function(x) foo(x[2], x[1]))
myData$Date <-dates

myData$Demand <-(rnorm(1,mean = 0, sd=1)+.75*myData$Adspend)

myData$Hour<-as.factor(myData$Hour)
```

#

```
AddCal <-function(DF,Date,Time,Seasonal=TRUE, Holiday=TRUE, Intraday = TRUE){
#Create variables of calendar effects from Date field
DF$Date<-as.Date(DF[[Date]], format="%m/%d/%Y")
DF[[Time]]<-factor(DF[[Time]], levels = c(1:24))
monthly <- months(DF[[Date]])
dow <-weekdays(DF[[Date]])
year1<-year(DF[[Date]])
quarter<-quarters(DF[[Date]])
```

#

## Create matrices of seasonal indicators for covariates

```
hmatx <- model.matrix(~as.factor(DF[[Time]]))[,2:24] # Matrix of hours
mmatx <- model.matrix(~as.factor(monthly))[,2:12] #Matrix of months
dmatx <- model.matrix(~as.factor(dow))[,2:7] #matrix of days of week
qmatx<-model.matrix(~as.factor(dow))[,1:3] #matrix of Quarters of the year
```

#

## Create Holiday indicator variables with both holiday and weekend flagged if within 2 days of holiday

```
LaborWkend<-ifelse(isWeekend(as.Date(USLaborDay(year1)+2)),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function that will take an array of dates and append the nearest weekend to each one, unless a date lands on Wednesday.

```
plusWeekends<-function(h){
  h<-as.Date(h)
  w<-as.POSIXlt(h)$wday 
  sort(unique(c(h,h[w %in% 0:2]-1,
        h[w %in% 1:2]-2,
        h[w == 2]-3,
        h[w ==4]+3,
        h[w %in% 4:5]+2,
        h[w %in% 4:6]+1)))
}
```

For example:

```
> plusWeekends(USLaborDay(2010:2012))
[1] "2010-09-04" "2010-09-05" "2010-09-06" "2011-09-03" "2011-09-04" "2011-09-05"
[7] "2012-09-01" "2012-09-02" "2012-09-03"
> plusWeekends(NewYearsDay(2010:2012))
[1] "2010-01-01" "2010-01-02" "2010-01-03" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-12-31"
[7] "2012-01-01"
```

To create your indicator, you could run something like

```
> indicator<-rep(0,length(dates))
> indicator[dates %in% plusWeekends(USLaborDay(2010:2012))]<-1
> dates[indicator==1]
[1] "2010-09-04" "2010-09-05" "2010-09-06" "2011-09-03" "2011-09-04" "2011-09-05"
[7] "2012-09-01" "2012-09-02" "2012-09-03"
```